# Computationally representing a Fuchsian group

Tags: representation-theory, galois-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, projective-space, nested-radicals

I'd like to learn the math behind [this code golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259038/100871), in which the symmetry group of [the order-4 pentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-4_pentagonal_tiling) is represented by integer matrices.

My understanding so far is: In $PSL(2,\Bbb R)$ acting on the [half-plane model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model), the matrix $S_\alpha=(\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&&0\\0&&1/\alpha\end{smallmatrix})$ implements a translation by distance $\log(\alpha^2)$ along a line containing $i$, and the matrix $R_\theta=(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\theta&&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&&\cos\theta\end{smallmatrix})$ implements a rotation by $2\theta$ radians around $i$, so we can find the side length of a pentagonal tile by solving $(S_\alpha R_{\pi/4})^5=\pm I$. (Alternatively, we could find the distance between adjacent tile centers by solving $(S_\alpha R_{\pi/5})^4=\pm I$, using [exact trigonometric values for $\pi/5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_values#Sine_of_18%C2%B0) to write down $R_{\pi/5}$.) We hope (or know?) that the solution $\alpha$ will live in a finite extension of $\Bbb Q$.

How does one proceed from here? Specifically:

1. Expanding the above equation in terms of $\alpha$ yields a system of degree-8 polynomials that I don't know how to solve. I put the matrix equation into Mathematica and it gave me solutions (to the $-I$ case—why?) equivalent to $\alpha=\sqrt{\phi\pm\sqrt\phi}$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. This justifies that we're working in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\phi+\sqrt\phi})$, as Anders asserted in a comment. But Mathematica didn't express the answer in terms of $\phi$. There seems to be some theory that I'm missing.
2. It looks like this field extension has degree at least $4$, because the entries in $S$ and $T$ are integer combinations of four irrational values. Is it $8$, corresponding to the different irrational values that appear as entries of $M$? How do we actually determine the degree and find a basis? (How do we obtain $\alpha=\frac1{\sqrt 2}(-\sqrt φ + φ + \sqrt φ^3)$? I feel like I'm missing tools for deriving identities among expressions involving square roots.)
3. If $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ has degree $\ge4$, then a matrix in $PSL(2,\Bbb Q(\alpha))$ is described by a tuple of $\ge16$ rational coefficients and thus $\ge32$ integers. Apparently we can golf this down to $16$ integers (and avoid fraction arithmetic) for our subgroup by noticing that it acts faithfully on a certain set of rational linear combinations of $16$ vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ in such a way that the denominators of the coefficients are bounded (here by 2). I suppose one could start figuring this out by examining the orbit of an arbitrary vector like $(0,1)$. Is that the right idea?

Any hints or references to relevant topics would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. […] But Mathematica didn't express the answer in terms of $\phi$. There seems to be some theory that I'm missing.

Personally I would take the distance for the translation not from the matrix equation you used, but from the [hyperbolic law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines). Using $\frac1{10}$ of your pentagon as a right-angled triangle with

$$
\alpha=\frac\pi5\qquad
\beta=\frac\pi4\qquad
\gamma=\frac\pi2\qquad
$$

you get half the edge length of the pentagon into the formula like this:

\begin{align*}
\cosh\left(\tfrac12\log(\alpha^2)\right) &=
\frac{\cos\frac\pi5+\cos\frac\pi4\cos\frac\pi2}
{\sin\frac\pi4\sin\frac\pi2} \\
\cosh\left(\log\alpha\right) &=
\frac{\frac\phi2+0}{\frac1{\sqrt2}} = \frac\phi{\sqrt2} \\
\log\alpha &= \log\left(\frac\phi{\sqrt2}+\sqrt{\left(\frac\phi{\sqrt2}\right)^2-1}\right) \\
\alpha &= \frac\phi{\sqrt2}+\sqrt{\frac{\phi^2-2}{2}}
\\
\alpha &= \frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\phi+\frac1{\sqrt\phi}\right)
\end{align*}

So you see the golden ratio enters the picture due to that $\cos\frac\pi5$.

> We hope (or know?) that the solution $\alpha$ will live in a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Sine and cosine of a rational multiple of $\pi$ will always be an algebraic number. So you know from that that $\alpha$ will be algebraic, and therefore $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ be a finite extension. Also your original matrix approach resulted in a polynomial equation with rational coefficients, which must lead to an algebraic solution.

> 2. […] How do we obtain $\alpha=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(-\sqrt\varphi+\varphi+\sqrt\varphi^3\right)$

In a sense, $\beta:=\sqrt\phi$ is the “smallest” or “most basic” relevant value in that parenthesis there. You get $\phi=\beta^2$ and you get $\frac1{\sqrt\phi}$ as $\beta^{-1}$. If you construct $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ and do computations in that, you find that $\beta^{-1}=\beta^3-\beta$. So I would guess that this observation is the reason we see $\sqrt\phi^3$ in there in the final form

$$\alpha=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\phi+\sqrt\phi^3-\sqrt\phi\right)$$

> 2. […] I feel like I'm missing tools for deriving identities among expressions involving square roots.

I'm not thinking about this primarily in terms of expressions in square roots. I'm thinking about this in terms of $\beta$ as an algebaric number, with $\beta^4-\beta^2-1=0$ as its defining (minimal) polynomial. With that in mind I get $\beta^4=\beta^2+1$ as a tool to limit the power of $\beta$ to at most $3$.

$$\mathbb Q(\beta)=\{a+b\beta+c\beta^2+d\beta^3\mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q\}$$

I can also write the defining polynomial equation as $\beta\left(\beta^3-\beta\right)=1$ to see that $\beta^3-\beta$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\beta$.

I got Sage to compute that minimal polynomial for me. But you could have done that from $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$, the minimal polynomial defining the golden ratio, and $\beta^2-\phi=0$ as an expression of the square root. Both of these are polynomials in $\phi$ and if you compute their resultant you should get the polynomial for $\beta$.

> 2. […] Is [the degree of the field extension] $8$, corresponding to the different irrational values that appear as entries of $M$?

Yes. You can either think of this as $\mathbb Q(\beta)(\sqrt2)$ i.e. a degree 2 extension of a degree 4 extension. Or you get the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ itself as

$$\alpha^8-2\alpha^6-2\alpha^4-2\alpha^2+1$$

which is of degree $8$ so that has to be the degree of the extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ in a single step. In terms of a suitable basis, the two separate extensions are closer to explaining the values used in the code golf. $\mathbb Q(\beta)(\tfrac1{\sqrt2})$ would be closer yet.

> 3. […] I suppose one could start figuring this out by examining the orbit of an arbitrary vector like $(0,1)$. Is that the right idea?

That's the way I see it, too, yes. Start with one point, see what other points come up, and how the coefficients align.

Looking at the lattice, I think you could also come up with a more geometric interpretation. What we essentially see there is on the one hand a combination of an axis-aligned square grid and a version of that rotated by $45°$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac1{\sqrt2} & 0 & -\frac1{\sqrt2} \\
0 & \frac1{\sqrt2} & 1 & \frac1{\sqrt2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

And then you combine that with coefficients from $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ in such a way that the individual rational dimensions of that field extension appear as separate dimensions of the resulting matrix. The first part of this construction takes care of the rotations, ensuring you can rotate, while the second part takes care of the translations.

Actually the part about the translation is not quite as obvious. $\alpha$ also contains that $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ coefficient in front. But you can use e.g.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt2}\\
\frac1{\sqrt2}
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt2}\\
-\frac1{\sqrt2}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac2{\sqrt2}\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

to get that factor in one of the coordinate axis directions. And it might even be that this is where the mentioned factor $2$ is coming from to keep things integral.

> If $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ has degree $\ge4$, then a matrix in $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb Q(\alpha))$ is described by a tuple of $\ge16$ rational coefficients and thus $\ge32$ integers. Apparently we can golf this down to $16$ integers […]

The degree of the field is $8$. That means that vectors are combinations of $16$ rational numbers. The chosen lattice actually doesn't simplify this, contrary to how I read that at first. A matrix acting on such a vector has $16^2$ integers, and you see that size in the code golf post.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is one of my first encounters with algebraic number fields, so I imagine a lot of this will become more intuitive to me over time. The method of computing resultants is something I wasn't aware of. Also, your profile picture is very appropriate :)